# Smooth scroll to specific div on click in css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a button, if you'd click it, it scrolls down smoothly to a specific div on the page by using css! (Without JS or jquery).
Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/
I couldn't understand in the code that gave what exactly does scroll smoothly?
My code:
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
  <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="#description" class="button" id="cn">Continue</a></li>
  </ul>
        <section id="description">
            <h2 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.5em; margin-top: 2em;">Description</h2>
            <section id="descr">
                    <div class="image desc"><img src="https://cdn.lynda.com/course/439683/439683-636441077028502313-16x9.jpg" width="800" height="550" title="Our company">
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h2>About Company</h2>
                        <p>Sometimes the mouse, but now it was the makeup of chocolate sauce ante powerful protein manufacturing sad sauce through a gateway.</p>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </section>
</html>
```

My css:

```
/* Button */
    .button {
        background: #ffff00;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 2.95em;
        line-height: 3em;
        padding: 0 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
#descr {
        display: flex;
        height: 90vh;
    }
        #descr .desc {
            padding: 3.5em 0 1.5em 0;
            padding-left: 2em;
            padding-right: 2em;
            background: #afdeed;
            width: 50%;
        }
        .image.desc img {
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px;
        }
        .image.desc img {
            animation: move 2s ease-in-out infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes move {
            0% {
                transform: translate(0);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translate(2.5em);
            }
        }
        .image.desc:hover img {
            animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
            0% {
                transform: translate(-5em);
            }
            25% {
                transform: rotate(20deg);
            }
            50% {
                transform: translate(5em);
            }
            75% {
                transform: rotate(-20deg);
            }
        }
```

I want that if button has clicked it'd scroll smoothly to the next div !

Comment: Do you know there's a specific Javascript/HTML/CSS tool (Ctrl-M) that allows us to run your code directly inside your question?

Comment: CSS can't do anything with a `click` you need JS for that.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not 100% sure of that. I believe the smooth effect has to do with either `transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;` or one of the `transform: translate[X,Y,Z]( 0 );` in the linked css

Comment: You can't apply anything on  a `click` without JS. CSS doesnt recognise it,

Comment: @Paulie_D well apparently `a[ id= "servicios" ]:target ~ #main article.panel` does something when you click on `servicios`. How would you explain the on-click scrolling effect in his linked jsfiddle **where there is no JS**?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, i'm about `a[ id= "servicios" ]:target ~ #main article.panel`, there is no JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is even **commented** in the CSS of your linked code:

```
/*
 *Scrolling
 */

a[ id= "servicios" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "galeria" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}
a[ id= "contacto" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
    transform: translateY( -1000px );
}
```

Add to this the fact that `panel` class has the following:

```
.panel {
    [...]
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    [...]
}
```

This makes it move smoothly instead of instantly.

```css
/* Button */
    .button {
        background: #ffff00;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 2.95em;
        line-height: 3em;
        padding: 0 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
    #descr {
        display: flex;
        height: 90vh;
    }
    #descr .desc {
        padding: 3.5em 0 1.5em 0;
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 2em;
        background: #afdeed;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .image.desc img {
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px;
    }
    .image.desc img {
        animation: move 2s ease-in-out infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes move {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(2.5em);
        }
    }
    .image.desc:hover img {
        animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-5em);
        }
        25% {
            transform: rotate(20deg);
        }
        50% {
            transform: translate(5em);
        }
        75% {
            transform: rotate(-20deg);
        }
    }
    
/*
 *Scrolling
 */

.panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}

a[ id= "descLink" ]:target ~ #description section.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -100px);
    transform: translateY( -100px );
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <a id="descLink"/>
  <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="#descLink" class="button" id="cn">Continue</a></li>
  </ul>
        <section id="description">
            <h2 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.5em; margin-top: 2em;">Description</h2>
            <section id="descr" class="panel">
                    <div class="image desc"><img src="https://cdn.lynda.com/course/439683/439683-636441077028502313-16x9.jpg" width="800" height="550" title="Our company">
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        <h2>About Company</h2>
                        <p>Sometimes the mouse, but now it was the makeup of chocolate sauce ante powerful protein manufacturing sad sauce through a gateway.</p>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </section>
</html>
```

I added `<a id="descLink"/>`, and changed the `href` so it links this, and I also added the `panel` class to the `descr` section for it to work.
You can then tweak the `translateY` value in the CSS to see how it renders.

Comment: And how does it help me?! Just copying and pasting, and so-so modifying isn't helping! I didn't downvote, mb smn else did! Sry

Comment: Your question is "*I couldn't understand in the code that gave what exactly does scroll smoothly*". I just highlighted the exact part that does scroll smoothly. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Ok I missed the `panel` part, so there I edited my answer

Comment: I edited my answer with a fiddle starting with your code, using parts of your jsfiddle link

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i'm realizing altogether!

Answer (score 2):

You probably made it to already work but here is a much easier solution for you that are looking for a simple answer.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **JQuery** for a `.click` effect. A simple, smooth button that takes you two a certain area within the same page, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use for this across the board. Requires jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Bind to body and use event bubbling
        // Much more efficient than binding to all links on the page
        $('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            // Default behaviour if the link isn't an anchor-link
            if(!href || href.substring(0, 1) != '#') {
                return true;
            }

            // Try for link to an id attribute
            var target = $(href);

            // If the anchor destination is added as <a name="" - look for this instead
            if(!target.length) {
                target = $('a[name="' + href.replace('#', '') + '"]:first');

                // If still no target, default behaviour
                if(!target.length) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            event.preventDefault();

            var targetTop = parseInt(target.offset().top),
                currentTop = parseInt($window.scrollTop());

            // Don't lock scrolling if we're already at the anchor
            if(targetTop != currentTop) {
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': Math.max(0, targetTop)
                }, 500);
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If you use carousels or tabs or other UI elements that rely on ID-linking, you may need to modify the selector, for example, one of my sites has this implemented as:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not(.carousel-control)', function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the effect in the demo you linked to is not a true scrolling, it's kind of scrolling emulation. There are two main part of it: [the `:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), which matches the element with the ID corresponding to the hash part of the current URL, and the `transition` property, that animates smoothly any other CSS property (in this case, the `transform`) property. As Rafalon correctly pointed out, the "magic" part of the CSS code is

```
a[ id= "galeria" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}
```

This CSS selector selects the `<article>` element with the `panel` class *inside* the element with the `#main` ID that goes after the `<a>` element with `id="galleria"` attribute in the same container, when this `<a>` element is navigated to (i.e. when the page URL ends with `#galleria`). If this condition is satisfied, this CSS rule applies to that `<article>` element the `transform` property that moves this element by 500px above. And because all `.panel` elements have `transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;` set, the vertical position of this panel changes not instantly, but for 0.6s (first accelerating, then decelerating, because of the ease-in-out [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function)).

However, you should keep in mind that this approach is rather hacky and has many limitations. But CSS has [the native property for the true smooth scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) — `scroll-behavior:smooth` (although not all browsers support it, it can be good progressive enhancement for your projects).